# Bound click loses context of my Class. JS

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I have this problem that I probably understand but don't know how to handle, if there is a way.

I have a class simplified as this:

```
function DrawingTable(canvas_id){
  this.canvas_id = canvas_id;
  bind_events()

  function bind_events(){
  $(get_canvas()).click(function(e){
    var canvas = get_canvas() //works
    do_something_in_the_instance_who_called_click()
  }

  function get_canvas(){return document.getElementById(canvas_id)}

  function do_something_in_the_instance_who_called_click(){ 
    alert(this.canvas_id) //fail!
  }

}
```

Because when the `click()` is invoked for what it looks **this** is not inside the instance anymore, but I need to change attributes from there. Is there a way, given that may be multiple instances?

I don't really know how but the get_canvas() works :)

I'm using jQuery but likely not relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are calling the function without any *object context*, but you can store the `this` value:

```
function DrawingTable(canvas_id){
  var instance = this;  // <-- store `this` value

  this.canvas_id = canvas_id;
  bind_events()

  function bind_events(){
  $(get_canvas()).click(function(e){
    // Note also that here the `this` value will point to the 
    // canvas elemenet, `instance` should be used also

    var canvas = get_canvas();
    do_something_in_the_instance_who_called_click();
  }

  function get_canvas(){return document.getElementById(canvas_id)}

  function do_something_in_the_instance_who_called_click(){ 
    alert(instance.canvas_id); // <-- use stored `this` value
  }

}
```

The `this` value is implicitly set when you make a function call, for example:

```
obj.method();
```

The `this` value will point to `obj`, if you make a function call without any *base object*, e.g.:

```
myFunction();
```

The `this` value inside `myFunction` will point to the global object.

Comment: +1 Great Great Explanation! Will just keep open for few more hours